# How to change desktop background image on windows with c++?

Tags: winapi

How to change the desktop background image on Windows?

Right now, I found this solution:

```
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID*)desktop_image_file, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

It works fine, but after a restart, the image is gone. How to save it permanently?

Comment: If you change the wallpaper yourself the normal way, does it also change back when you restart?

Comment: Hi alanis, if the answer solves your issue you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Feel free let me know if you have any concern.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` flag:

> SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE
>   **Writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile.**

```
SystemParametersInfoA(..., SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```